# arcgis 10.0 od matrix only solves A-A, B-B, C-C, not A-B, A-C, etc

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, origin-destination

I think I have a very noob question here. Using ArcGIS 10.0 and Network Analyst extension to create Origin-Destination Matrix. I have a shapefile of 120 points, and I want to create a matrix of shortest road network distances between all 120 points (120x120 matrix). I've tried using network datasets that (a) include the road network + points and (b) include road network only.

Using the OD tool, I load the points as both origins and destinations, so both read (120) once loaded. I set impedance to length, no cutoff value, and destinations to find `<All>`.

When I solve, I get lines (120), and the attribute table shows only 120 pairs: each point with itself. So all distances are 0. In other words, I get A-A, B-B, C-C, etc, not A-A, A-B, A-C, B-B, B-C, etc.

**Update**
Here are links to the [road network dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/baezn6quka250ya/roads.zip) and [origins-destinations](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aejnuruv054oe0d/villages.zip).

Comment: Since you are using the oldest supported release, and it had five service packs, it would help if you specified which SP you were using.

Comment: thanks. build 2414, which looks to be ArcGIS Desktop 10 final, no SP.

Comment: It's usually considered best practice to wait a week or three after release before applying a service pack (except for SP1, especially if it's released concurrently with the new build), so that puts you nearly 3 years behind in applying SP1, and twenty some-odd months behind in applying SP5.  Have you tried reviewing the 20-25 pages of fixed defects, to see if any apply?

Comment: yes, installing the SPs make sense. i don't use Arc on a regular basis, but worth installing to see if my problem is resolved. i'll do this. i figured my problem was more basic an unrelated to builds, but you might be right.

Comment: @Vince, I successfully updated 10.0 through SP5, but no still no luck with the OD Matrix tool. It only produces 120 lines, A-A, B-B, C-C, etc.

Comment: I added links to the network dataset and points shapefile I'm using in case anyone is willing to try it out. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to circumvent the problem (which was probably just user error all along) by using the network analyst toolboxes (rather than the properties of the o-d layer) to (1) create the o-d layer, (2) add locations (twice, once for origins and destinations, adding the same point layer each time), and (3) solve.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check that the 'Destinations To Find' parameter of the OD Cost Matrix layer is set to 'All' (not to 1)?

[image]

Comment: thanks. yes, in my original post, i did not wrap `<All>` in backticks, so it did not show. this was the setting i used.